# How can I create a hyperlink to a Lotus Notes mailgroup?

Tags: email, lotus-notes, hyperlink

Quite simple: I have a mailgroup in Lotus Notes, e.g. "1234_Mailgroup_SP". How can I place this on a webpage and make it a clickable link, that will open Lotus Notes, and create a new e-mail to this group?

This post had a very promising title: "How to create a link to a lotus notes group email box", but the user just stated that he knew how to get that link...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your groups have internet email addresses, you can just use a regular html mailto: link and it'll work. I imagine the email to field would popular fine even if you just put did a mailto: link and the regular name of the group too assuming it's all internal to your company.

Comment: Note that this will open the default mail client. Which can be different from notes. But to all intends and purposes opening the default mail client is the right thing to do. And you can mail to a regular mail address or to a list address.

Comment: Thanks both! A regular mailto did the trick, I would (obviously) never guess it was that easy. So yes, Lotus Notes is set as the default mail client.